# Chrome/Chromium kill site's Javascript without closing it || See what's causing an infinite javascript loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm trying to debug a **Javascript** infinite-loop in a WordPress plugin and I need to check the performance tab to see what part causes the loop.

I'm able to run the Performance test, but it stops on Processing profile, because the site is still looping in the background.

Is there a way to kill the site without closing it and devtools?

Comment: What you want is the debugger in the "Sources" tab, not the performance test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel W. Mentioned in the comments that I need the Sources tab and there indeed is an option to stop JavaScript execution with a Call stack below.

See more: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-67/#stop